# Print object in mongo script

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I print to console an object in a Mongo script?

I tried:

```
> print({})
[object Object]
```

It simply displays `[object Object]`. Which is the alternative for `console.dir()`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `printjson` for that:

```
> printjson({})
{ }

> printjson({a: 'foo', b: 'bar'})
{ "a" : "foo", "b" : "bar" }
```

Comment: You learn something new every day :) 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#print

Comment: Is there not a method to print in an actual object format rather than json, i.e. { a: "foo", b: "bar" } without the keys in quotes

Answer (score 6):

If all I want to do is take a look at the contents, I'll usually just use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
> print ( JSON.stringify( { "foo": { "bar": "spam" } } ) )
```

Comment: Ah, it's `printjson`. See JohnnyHK's answer.

Comment: FYI, `JSON.stringify` will remove mongo's `ObjectId` from the output - `{"_id":{},"field":"value"}` `printjson` will work ok, printing `{"_id":ObjectId("54cc2153b0a9961f7ceae2ba"),"field":"value"}`